# NestJS GraphQL - Do you need custom decorators to access gql @Req and @Res?

Tags: cookies, graphql, nestjs

I'm ultimately trying to set cookies in my graphql resolver response and as far as I'm aware, you can only do it via `response.cookie()` or `response.setHeader()`. As a result, I'm trying to get the response object from the query.

Does @Req and @Res work with graphql like with http? I feel like it doesn't...

```js
import { Req, Res, Response } from "@nestjs/common";

// ...

  @Query(() => User)
  async getUser(
    @Req() req: RequestWithUser,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response,
  ): Promise<User> {
    console.log("req:", req);
    return { email: "admin@gmail.com" };
  }
```

So I just want to confirm, we need to create a separate custom decorator for `@GqlReq` and `@GqlRes` like below right for the response right?

```js
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from "@nestjs/common";
import { GqlExecutionContext } from "@nestjs/graphql";

export const GqlRes = createParamDecorator(
  (_data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    if (context.getType() === "http") {
      return context.switchToHttp().getResponse(); // <- I think this is right
    }

    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req.res; 
    // ^ Is this right? How do you get the response object? 
    // My intellisence isn't showing it properly
  },
);
```

So to summarize my questions:

1. In graphql, it's standard to write custom decorators for `Req` and `Res` right?
2. How do you get the response object in graphql?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@Context()` annotation to get the request context, and `@Context('req')` to get the `req` property.

In your example:

```
@Query(() => User)
  async getUser(
    @Context('req') req: Request
  ): Promise<User> {
    const res = req.res;
    console.log("req:", req);
    console.log("res:", res);
    return { email: "admin@gmail.com" };
  }
```

This is documented in [the nestJS official doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#graphql-argument-decorators)

Hope this helps!